# PHP MYSQL - Get Rank (Position) of Single user Based on multiples rows

Tags: mysql, ranking

With the following MySQL table:

```
+---------+-----------+
| user_id | user_name |
+---------+-----------+
|    1    |   user 1  |
|    2    |   user 2  |
|    3    |   user 3  |
|    4    |   user 4  |
|    5    |   user 5  |
+---------+-----------+
+---------+-------------+
| user_id | user_staff  |
+---------+-------------+
|    1    |  xxxxxx     |
|    1    |  xxxxxx     |
|    2    |  xxxxxx     |
|    2    |  xxxxxx     |
|    2    |  xxxxxx     |
|    3    |  xxxxxx     |
|    3    |  xxxxxx     |
|    4    |  xxxxxx     |
+---------+-------------+
```

This Query get me the Ranking table:

```
SELECT usr.user_name, COUNT(stf.user_id) AS score 
  FROM table_stafs AS stf 
    LEFT JOIN table_users AS usr ON usr.user_id=stf.user_id 
  GROUP BY usr.id 
  ORDER BY score DESC
```

How can get the position of a single user?

Comment: The position is the record number as you sort by score.

Comment: I need a query to get the position on a single user based on the number of staff rows table

Comment: something like in here? https://stackoverflow.com/q/3333665/367456

Answer (score 0):

You can add an auto increment column in the query result if you want ranks, e.g.:

```
SELECT usr.user_id,COUNT(stf.*) AS score, @r := @r + 1 AS rank
FROM table_stafs AS stf, (SELECT @r := 0) a 
LEFT JOIN table_users AS usr ON usr.user_id=stf.user_id 
GROUP BY usr.id ORDER BY score DESC
```

Comment: If you believe this is the answer, suggest the existing Q&A material on the website (via a comment and a close vote).

Comment: this gave me the count of all rows in the table_staff not the count of a single user by user_id :/